# jQuery function that returns caller's data value

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I return the anchor tags' `data-test` value so I can use this function on anchors with different `data-test` values?

```
<a href='#' data-test='some text'></a>
```

```js
function getAnchor(){
    // do stuff
    console.log($(this).data('test'));
}

$('a').on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault; //prevent anchor behaviour.
    getAnchor();
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does the "this" keyword work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Comment: `e.preventDefault; //prevent anchor behaviour.` No it doesn't. You need to call it `e.preventDefault();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several options:

Pass the `this` reference to the function as a parameter:

```
function getAnchor(el) {
    console.log($(el).data('test'));
}

$('a').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    getAnchor(this);
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/g8yfcxkm/)

Use `call` to set the context of the function being executed:

```
function getAnchor() {
    console.log($(this).data('test'));
}

$('a').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    getAnchor.call(this);
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/fxtj4npz/)

Provide the reference of the function to the `click` handler:

```
function getAnchor(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log($(this).data('test'));
}

$('a').on('click', getAnchor);
```

[**Example fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/z718e5pj/2/)

Answer (score 0):

the problem `$(this)` in your function will refer to nothing

```js
function getAnchor(element){
  //do stuff
  console.log($(element).data('test'));
}
$('a').on('click',function(e){
  e.preventDefault(); //prevent anchor behaviour.
  getAnchor($(this));  // or getAnchor(this);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href='#' data-test='some text'>Click Me</a>
```

Comment: To be pedantic, it will refer to the `window` object.